# MySQL create temporary table with autoincrement from SELECT only

Tags: mysql, sql, select, auto-increment, temporary-objects

With MySQL
I know it's possible to create a temporary table from a SELECT:
[Create a temporary table in a SELECT statement without a separate CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table)

I also know it's possible to create autoincrement in a temporary table:
[Auto Increment in Temporary Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184375/auto-increment-in-temporary-table)

I want to do both at the same time: create a temporary table from a SELECT statement and I want the temporary table to have an auto increment column.

It is possible to do that?

Comment: Thank you but I must create the temporary table from the select itself (no create temporary table before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a temporary table with a row number column, then use variables:

```
create temporary table temp as
    select (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum, t.*
    from t cross join
         (select @rn := 0) vars;
```

This will not be auto-incrementing for new `insert`s.  If you need that, you'll need to alter the table definition.